# echo a form input with backslashes

Tags: php, forms, input, echo, backslash

trying to get the html code working by using echo,

this works as html:

```
<input type="text" name="ordernum" value="<?= isset($_POST['ordernum']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['ordernum']) : '' ?>" />
```

but when I escape the value with backslash ( i have tried dozens of combinations and read a lot on stackoverflow,but still cant fix it) I get unexpected T_STRING errors .

```
echo ' <input type="text" name="ordernum" value=\'= isset($_POST['ordernum']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['ordernum']) : '' \' />';
```

Comment: You can't just write arbitrary PHP code *in the middle of a string literal*.

Answer (score 0):

As [Quentin has commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23738996/echo-a-form-input-with-backslashes#comment36492633_23738996):

> You can't just write arbitrary PHP code in the middle of a string literal

It's because of the `$_POST['ordernum']` part.

Re-write it like this:

```
$val = isset($_POST["ordernumW]) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST["ordernum"]) : "";

echo "<input type='text' name='ordernum' value='$val' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use *arbitrary* code in a string literal. First assign the value in one variable and use that variable in `echo` statement.

```
$orderNum = isset($_POST['ordernum']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['ordernum']) : '';
echo ' <input type="text" name="ordernum" value="'.$orderNum.'" />';
```

Comment: A ternary condition is perfectly valid in a string definition. You should just remove the `<?=` and `?>` tags and properly concatenate ;-)

Comment: @user3556674 ok and accept this answer and close this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape with `\` the characters that may end your string (i.e. specifically string delimiters `"` and `'`).

Those two lines work:

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"ordernum\" value=\"" . (isset($_POST['ordernum']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['ordernum']) : '') . "\" />";
echo '<input type="text" name="ordernum" value="' . (isset($_POST['ordernum']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['ordernum']) : '') . '" />';
```

Comment: as already said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23738996/echo-a-form-input-with-backslashes#comment36492633_23738996) you cannot use arbitrary condition inside a string

Comment: This code is perfectly valid. The ternary condition evaluates to either the HTML-escaped version of `$_POST['ordernum']` or the empty string, which is concatenated to the first part. You can't use a `if` statement in a string definition, but there's nothing preventing you from concatenating literals, function results or ternary conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This is what it should be:

```
echo('<input type="text" name="ordernum" value="'.(isset($_POST['ordernum'])?htmlspecialchars($_POST['ordernum']):'').'">');
```

You use a full-stop to concatenate strings, so you should be ending the first portion of the string, adding a full-stop, then the dynamic value, another full stop, then the remainder of the string.

So in you're string, what you're doing wrong is here:

```
value=\'= isset($_POST['ordernum']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['ordernum']) : '' \'
```

Like this:

```
"first part of string".$myvariable."last part of string";
```

You only need to escape the quote type which the string is contained by also:

```
"I need to escape this \" but not this ' "
'I need to escape this \' but not this " '
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$val = isset($_POST['ordernum']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['ordernum']) : '';

echo '<input type="text" name="ordernum" value="'. $val. '" />';
```

Comment: What advantage does this bring over the ternary if statement?